# proper guide to adding a gripper to my robot in rviz2 and moveit2

Tags: ros, ros2, rviz, moveit, gripper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

im currently running ros2 on foxy and using this driver for the UR10e https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/ which works perfectly fine, but now im trying to add a gripper to this setup to properly control everything with moveit2. I have assembled my own action server for the gripper. The gripper i have is the Robotiq Hand-E.

Unfortunately I dont know where to start with adding the gripper to my virtual setup.
Do I have to rewrite all urdf and srdf files?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could guide me through the process

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383794/proper-guide-to-adding-a-gripper-to-my-robot-in-rviz2-and-moveit2/) by [takti](https://answers.ros.org/users/79610/takti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-08-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anujros2noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/108674/anujros2noob/) on 2022-06-21**:
Hello @takti,

do you mind sharing the action server that you have created. it would be really helpful if you can provide me with it as I am new to ROS and cannot find any gripper that can be controlled using ROS2 or has a dedicated ROS2 driver. Please do let me know if it is possible for you to share the action server with me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello @takti,

You just have to add in your URDF including your link, join. Then you have to upload that urdf file into your moveit and configure your gripper into the moveit.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [errixerri](https://answers.ros.org/users/116944/errixerri/) on 2022-10-18**:
hi, it's still confusing how you wrote it, could you be a bit more specific? Thank you